# Docker build ERROR failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token"

Tags: docker

I can install successfully install Docker `version 24.0.5, build ced0996` in my computer. I am using window 10. I clone code docker started app from GitHub.

```
git clone https://github.com/docker/getting-started-app.git
```

After clone success code, I get project with structure:

[image]

I create Dockerfile with content as bellow:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

When open `cmd command line` and run `docker build -t getting-started .` I get this error:

[image]

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/2165

Comment: No error and works well in my windows 11 and Docker version 24.0.2